# How to make the width of a VStack grow based on the width of a Text

Tags: swift, swiftui

What I need is to be able to create a `VStack` where its width grows if the `Text` inside grows. I also would like to be able to maintain the `VStack` minimum width at `180pt` if possible.

The following code does almost what I need except it doesn't have a minimum width; which I can live without. The issue with the code below is that I'm getting a purple warning when I test it on a device.

Any idea why am I getting the warning below?

Bye the way, I get no errors, just the warning.

```
struct GeneralTest: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("244GGDD")
                .frame(width: .infinity, height: 55, alignment: .center)
                .font(Font.system(size: 42, weight: .light))
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                .padding(.leading, 20)
                .padding(.trailing, 20)

        }
        .frame(width:.infinity, height: 100, alignment: .center)
        .background(Color.gray)
    }
}
```

### Warning:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following modifiers should give you what you need:

```
Text("244GGDD")
    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
    .frame(minWidth: 180)
    // other modifiers
```

The `VStack` should wrap the whole text, which will be minimum 180 points wide.

Comment: With your code, I was able to achieve what I was looking for. I also had to add  
`.frame(height: 100, alignment: .center)` to the `VStack` since I needed the VStack height to be 100 pts. Thanks